# GNAT GPL 2016 Installation Hassle On Windows XP SP3

Tags: windows, windows-xp, ada, gnat

About 2 weeks ago I installed the new 2016 version of the GNAT GPL Ada/SPARK compiler and associated software tools.

But the damn thing won't work right.

Running existing projects on it, it just won't compile and shows some errors with Python files.

Anyone else experience this problem ?

I'm (still) using Win XP as the platform for the GNAT GPL dev tools.

**EDIT**

Just saw this on a ReadMe file : This version of GNAT GPL is officially supported on the following hosts. Please see the "Special Notes" section immediately following the targets section for special instructions relevant to specific platforms. PC/x86 and x86_64 - Windows Vista Business, 7, 8, 8.1, and 10 So it looks like GNAT 2016 won't run any longer on Win XP machines.

[image]

Comment: "some errors" is artfully unspecific, and the screen dump (a) is unreadable and (b) doesn't appear to show all the errors. So the best anyone can say is likely to be "something went wrong somewhere". If you want more specific help, report the actual error messages - especially the first few and last,

Answer (score 0):

The errors seem to be in the jedi library, part of python.
Did you install in a new directory, or over an existing install ? I would recommend the former, so you likely should redo the install from scratch, and in a new directory.

Comment: Does it matter if it's a 32 bit PC ? Or if it uses Windows XP ?

Answer (score 0):

I simply disable "jedi support" plugin inside  Tools/Plugins and everything works perfectly.  This plugin is completion for python editor, maybe you don't need it for ada.

Comment: I did that. Now I have the error [2016-07-23 09:50:26] C:\GNAT\2016\share\doc\gprbuild\html\gps_index.xml:1:0: No root element specified                                                                                                        Maybe I need to find another setting for this.

Comment: Found this link discussing the same error :  http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.ada.macosx

Comment: Pascal's idea removed the "No root element" error. But the project building still gets stuck in a loop. No use making a new project either. Once a new .adb file is opened the hourglass is on again . . .  It must be an XP restriction.

Comment: This error "No root element" is present in my installation to, it is on windows 10 64bit, but it not seem harmful to anything else. Isn't this some sort of help to documentation link ?

Comment: Creating this missing gps_index.xml file did the trick, thanks !

Comment: Indeed it is caused by non-acceptance of the XP system. Old projects working fine on Windows 10 now . . .